# python os.system from input nor working

Tags: python, os.system

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import subprocess
mail=raw_input("")
os.system("mail" + mail + "<<<test")
```

When I run this program I`ve got error :sh: 1: Syntax error: redirection unexpected.

The script must send mail using mailutilis

Comment: What do you get when you execute "mail<yourinput><<<test" on your OS shell i.e Command prompt (windows) or Shell in Unix

Comment: sh: 1: Syntax error: redirection unexpected

Comment: So its nothing to do with python, figure out the exact shell command which you need fire

Comment: Try replacing your OS command with 
`os.system("mail" + "  " + str(mail) + " " + "< test")`

Comment: @saurabh not working

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `os.system`. Replace it with `subprocess.Popen`:

```
address = raw_input()
with open('test') as text:
    subprocess.Popen(["mail", address], stdin=text).wait()
```